# Subharmonocity and Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, greens-theorem

[image]

My Try:

I was going to use the Green's theorem but couldn't since we don't know whether $u,v\in C^2(\partial D)$. I have no other idea to start. Can anybody please give me a hint?

Comment: Assuming $u, v \in C^2(D) \cap C^1(\bar D)$ should be enough to apply Green's formula. (Look up Green's identities for the quickest route.)

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why. By the way, if we can apply, then it gives only the equality of the given inequality.